# minimumLineSpacing for some cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to change `minimumLineSpacing` for some cells depending on what row they are.

Imagine having 10 cells; I want `minimumLineSpacing` to be 8 for all of them **except** for cell number 7.

I tried doing it via delegate:

`- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section`

But I just **wish** that it would pass back a `NSIndexPath` instead of a section.

I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One workaround:**

If you have it subclassed , you should be able to do this very easy with autolayout and a XIB.

**Example:**
If you have a constraint in the cell to the bottom of the contentView, you can simply set the constraint to an **NSLayoutConstraint** property and update the **constant** of the constraint for that specific cell only to give an extra spacing.

To keep the same proportions and height as the rest of the cells, you only add the extra spacing (**same as you added to the constant**) to the itemSize.height to that specific cell.

If you don't have this subclassed with autolayout or anything. You can do it programatically the same way but with a subView frame CGRect